# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmkl_rt When compiling makefile

Tags: gcc, linker, fortran, shared-libraries, intel

here is the make file

```
# EXTRALIBS = -L/opt/SUNWspro/lib -lF77 -lM77 -lsunmath  -lfsu
# LAPACK = -L/home/bramley/lib -llapack95
# BLAS = -L/home/bramley/lib -lblas95
# F95= /usr/local/intel/compiler60/ia32/bin/ifc
# OPTS= -O -w
# LIBS = $(LAPACK) $(BLAS)

include make.inc

runLU: luDriver.o LU8.o LU4.o rowswp.o elapsedtime.o kinds.mod \
    utilities.o swaps.o checkLU.o WriteParameters.o writeB.o Writeipiv.o 
    $(F95) $(INCS) -o runLU $(OPTS) luDriver.o LU8.o LU4.o kinds.o \
        utilities.o swaps.o elapsedtime.o WriteParameters.o checkLU.o \
        rowswp.o  writeB.o Writeipiv.o $(LIBS)

luDriver.o: luDriver.f90 kinds.mod 
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c luDriver.f90
LU4.o: LU4.c
    $(CC) $(INCS) $(OPTS) -c LU4.c
LU8.o: LU8.c
    $(CC) $(INCS) $(OPTS) -c LU8.c

rowswp.o: rowswp.f90 kinds.mod
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c rowswp.f90

WriteParameters.o: WriteParameters.f90 
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c WriteParameters.f90

kinds.mod: kinds.f90 
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c kinds.f90

elapsedtime.o: elapsedtime.f90 
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c elapsedtime.f90

checkLU.o: checkLU.f90 kinds.mod 
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c checkLU.f90

swaps.o: swaps.f90 kinds.mod 
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c swaps.f90

utilities.o: utilities.f90 kinds.mod
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c utilities.f90

writeB.o: writeB.f90 
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c writeB.f90

Writeipiv.o: Writeipiv.f90 
    $(F95) $(OPTS) -c Writeipiv.f90

clean:
    /bin/rm -f *.o *.mod runLU log B ipiv

kleen:
    /bin/rm -f *.o *.mod runLU log results B ipiv
```

and here is make.inc

```
# F90 = ifort
F90 = gfortran
CC = gcc
F95 = $(F90)
OPTS = -O3 

MKLROOT = /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl

LIBS =   -L$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt -lpthread -lm
INCS = -I.
```

WHat should i do here when it says -lmkl_rt is not found ???

Comment: Check, using `ls` or similar, that `/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.3.163/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so` exists. On my installation of MKL, for example, there is another level of directory structure in the path to the library files.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
 source /opt/intel/composerxe/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

(best to put it in `bash_profile`). Adjust the path according to your installation.

It sets the correct `LIBRARY_PATH` variable (not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that is for runtime!)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and point it to the directory containing the missing library.